# Constructive proofs for statements about rational numbers in Constructive Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, constructive-mathematics

On page 26 of Bishop and Bridges "Constructive Analysis", in a proof of "If $x_1,...,x_n$ are real numbers such that $x_1 + ...+x_n$>0, then for some $i$, $x_i>0$", it seems to me this lemma is used without proof:

If for each $a_i$, $a_i\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $p \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i > \frac{1}{2}p \Rightarrow \exists i: a_i > \frac{1}{2n}p$.

This is classically obvious but seems to use LEM/proof by contradiction, and is therefore non-constructive. I would (classically) prove the statement by assuming $\forall i : a_i\leq\frac{1}{2n}p$ and show that implies $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \leq \frac{1}{2}p$. So $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i > \frac{1}{2}p \Rightarrow \neg \forall i : a_i\leq\frac{1}{2n}p \Rightarrow \exists i: a_i > \frac{1}{2n}p$ but it is my understanding that the last step is nonconstructive. What is the constructive way to do this?

Further in the very next proof, he asserts "For each n in $\mathbb{Z}^+$, either $x_n \leq n^{-1}$ or $x_n > n^{-1}$," where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$. This seems like classic LEM: how is it not?

I'm very new to constructive math so sorry if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two constructively valid facts are being used here. First, inequality between rational numbers is decidable. Thus, if $x$ and $y$ are rational then $x<y$ or $x=y$ or $x>y$.  The (constructive) proof of this proceeds by using the definition of $<$ and $=$ for rational numbers in terms of the corresponding relations on natural numbers; the fact that natural numbers satisfy $x<y$ or $x=y$ or $x>y$ is proved by induction.

Second, although decidability is not generally preserved by quantification, it is preserved by quantification over finite sets. In particular, if one has, for all natural numbers $i\leq n$, that $\phi(i)\lor\neg\phi(i)$, then it follows that $[(\exists i\leq n)\,\phi(i)]\lor[(\forall i\leq n)\,\neg\phi(i)]$. Again, the (constructive) proof of this is by induction on $n$.